# How to locate the time choosing button in Yahoo.finance?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, yahoo-finance

I want to locate the time choosing button with in [Yahoo Stock History](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL) page:

Snapshot of the element:
![enter image description here][2]

but the python code I write by xpath is unable to make it.The code is shown as follow:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 180).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//svg[@class="Va(m)! Mstart(8px) Stk($linkColor) Fill($linkColor) dateRangeBtn:h_Fill($linkActiveColor) 
button1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//svg[@class="Va(m)! Mstart(8px) Stk($linkColor) Fill($linkColor) dateRangeBtn:h_Fill($linkActiveColor) dateRangeBtn:h_Stk($linkActiveColor) W(8px) H(8px) Cur(p)"]')
```

But it will show the errors as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URyeD.png)
or
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsHXV.png)
Please give me some help or suggestions.I have no idea why it can not be found.

Comment: It appears you didn't quite fully copy the code from pycharm. In the future, try to give as little information in the form of pictures, and copy and paste the error codes into your post. It makes it easier for others to help.

Comment: Sorry,I will do it next time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The element is a dynamic element. So to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section[data-test=qsp-historical] div[data-test=dropdown] > div > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//section[@data-test='qsp-historical']//div[@data-test='dropdown']/div/span"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```